# firebase Re-Authentication ios

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make User Authentication but I got the error:

> Credential used before its being initialized

My code below:

```
if error._code == 17014 {
                            // required recent authentication
                            let credential: AuthCredential

                            user.reauthenticateAndRetrieveData(with: credential, completion: nil)

                        }
                    }else {
                        self.ShowAlert(title: "succeed", message: "mail Updated")
                    }
                })
            }

        }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the credential. If this is an email/password user, you should ask the user to provide the password. If this is an OAuth user, get a new OAuth credential. You would then initialize the Firebase AuthCredential with those and reauthenticate.